# jQuery mobile won't let me use a custom class-name

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

**TL;DR**: This fiddle shows the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/kRG95/1/

My use case does not allow IDs on these select elements (they come from a template that is rendered multiple times). If I use classNames, jQuery mobile renders the selects incorrectly (double-wrapping).

Is there a known workaround for this? Le Google hasn't shown me anything.

For completeness, the following code **does not** work:

```
$(".one, .two").selectmenu();

$(".two").selectmenu("disable");

$(".one").on("change", function(){
    $(".two").selectmenu("enable");
});

$("body").trigger("create");
```

But if I change those classNames to ids, like so:

```
$("#one, #two").selectmenu();

$("#two").selectmenu("disable");

$("#one").on("change", function(){
    $("#two").selectmenu("enable");
});

$("body").trigger("create");
```

Everything works as expected.

The specific error (since I was asked):

`Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on selectmenu prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'disable'`

Comment: For lazy testers, here's the working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/PgAeH/

Comment: *"jQuery mobile misbehaves and throws errors"* Misbehaves how? What errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since jQuery Mobile propagates the class to another elements when the inputs are widgetized you should add the select tag to your selectors

```
$("select.one, select.two").selectmenu();

$("select.two").first().selectmenu("disable");

$("select.one").on("change", function(){
    $("select.two").selectmenu("enable");
});

$("body").trigger("create");
```

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kRG95/3/)**

Comment: For those curious to know why, that is because jQuery Mobile's page initialization routine already enhances the `<select>` elements. During this process, other elements are created and some of them repeat the classes exposed by the original elements. `$(".one, .two")` ends up matching four elements instead of two.

Comment: That did the trick. I should have caught that it was propagating the className up the generated DOM tree. Thanks so much!